# Почему default_character_set в my.ini не настраивает кодировку client, results, connection и даже если их установить явно выводятся "кракозябры"?

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, mariadb

**У меня два вопроса:**

1. Почему default_character_set в my.ini (my.cnf) не задает кодировку для character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection (установлены в cp1251)? - из-за этого в PMA и php-скриптах выводятся "кракозябры" вместо кириллицы, **НО** в cmd кириллица выводится нормально
2. Почему даже при явном указании character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection через SET NAMES ... выводятся кракозябры вместо кириллицы, но теперь и в cmd (даже те данные, что были занесены уже после выполнения команды SET NAMES utf8).

my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci’
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8
[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

**Дополнительная информация к вопросу №1:**

В cmd прописываю команды mysql:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char %';
```

Выводится:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | cp1251                         |
| character_set_connection | cp1251                         |
| character_set_database   | utf8                           |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | cp1251                         |
| character_set_server     | utf8                           |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Почему character_set_client, character_set_results и character_set_connection установлены в cp1251, а не в utf8? Я же прописал в my.ini default-character-set = utf8

При этом при занесении и извлечении данных через cmd кириллица отображается нормально, но если просмотреть содержимое таблиц через phpMyAdmin или извлекать данные через php-скрипт, то будут отображаться "кракозябры" вместо кириллицы (в php-скрипте я задаю кодировку utf-8).

**Дополнительная информация к вопросу №2:**

Если выставить utf8 явно через cmd с помощью команды SET NAMES utf8, то кириллица перестает нормально отображаться и через cmd. Я подумал, возможно это связано с тем, что кириллица была занесена, когда  character_set_client, character_set_results и character_set_connection были установлены в cp1251, поэтому я решил занести еще данные в таблицу уже после выполнения команды SET NAMES, но это не помогло - всё равно выводятся кракозябры. Правда кракозябры, которые были занесены до SET NAMES и после выглядят по разному.
 
**До:** что-то типа  ╨М╥Р╨З┬о╨О╥Р┬д╨Б┬м╨╗┬й

**После:** что-то типа ??????? ?рав??тел?

**В чем может быть проблема(ы)? Как сделать так, чтобы была правильно установлена кодировка и всё работало?**

Надеюсь на помощь. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1. забыть 1251 как страшный сон.
2. забыть про default_character_set
3. выкинуть все существующие данные.

после этого сделать по-человечески:

1. при создании таблиц явно задавать кодировку utf8mb4
2. при соединении из пхп задавать ту же кодировку, только делать это правильно, не через set names а через set_charset в mysqli или DSN в PDO
3. Не забыть выставить правильную кодировку страницы UTF-8 через header/php.ini

Comment: Я удалил таблицу. Создал ее еще раз уже с кодировкой utf8mb4 сравнение utf8mb4_unicode_ci, занес данные, но в PMA почему-то выводит вот это: ЌҐЇ®ЎҐ¤Ё¬л©

Comment: значит пма кривой